# What is the default TIFF orientation?

Tags: c++, image-processing, orientation, default, tiff

I'm working with some tiff data and I've come upon a few test images that do not have orientation data. They appeared to me upside down so I defaulted the orientation to ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT which seems to be working.

I'm curious though, what is the accepted default orientation? I noticed that most software just ignores orientation data anyway. Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/orientation.html) says that "default 1". In the same page, it explains that 1 = top left.

So it would seem that whatever software you are using to read the file later is non-conformant.

Comment: Could you please link to that document?

Comment: @John: Done - sorry, thought I had done that, but obviously somewhere in the switching back and forth between tabs, I forgot I hadn't... :(